# How to specify the InputField as a String in Manipulate

Tags: manipulate, inputfield

I'm putting together a Demonstration which utilizes a function which operates on a (manipulated) `String`, and I'd like the `InputField` to be of the form `InputField[col,String,FieldSize->3]`. Using the default format gives something like this:

```
Manipulate[col, {{col, "AB"}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

which requires use of quotation marks.

I'm able to hack the function to take expressions and convert them to strings

```
f[column_String] := column
f[column_] := ToString@HoldForm@column
```

but then the `InputField` looks strange for `I` or `E`:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I found another possible workaround [on MathGroup](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2010/Jul/msg00373.html):

```
col="AB"
Manipulate[Grid[{{InputField[Dynamic[col], String, FieldSize -> 3], f@col}}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

However, this requires pre-initializing `col` and messes up multiple `Manipulate` instances.

Is there a way to have `Manipulate` assume that what's entered in an `InputField` is a `String`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I thought this was undocumented, but actually it just seems to be obscure. The documentation for `ControlType` mentions, [under the "More Information" section](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ControlType.html#50956569),

> Arbitrary controls can be set up in `Manipulate` by giving control specifications of the form {*u*, *func*}.

So,

```
Manipulate[InputForm[col], {col, "AB", InputField[#, String] &}]
```

gives (with a different string entered for demonstrative purposes):

[image: picture of a Manipulate with a string-type InputField]

Comment: I completely missed that in the "More Information" section. Sorry for the RTFM question.

Comment: @EliLansey: I think [nearly everyone](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/35370/37) misses that information.

Comment: Note that if you need to additionally specify the label, then the syntax will be `{{col, "AB", "My control"}, InputField[#, String] &}` — note the placement of the extra braces inside.