# Is there a way to make the "Details" section of the Documentation expanded by default?

Tags: front-end, documentation, customization, configuration

By default, the *Mathematica* documentation opens with the "Details" section collapsed.

[image]

This is *never* what I'm looking for — in fact, I've lost count of the times I've sought help on a feature and not found it anywhere on the feature's Documentation page (at least not until I remember this shortcoming).

Is there a way to configure *Mathematica* so that the "Details" section of the Documentation is always expanded by default?

Comment: New edit should be more handy, what do you think?

Comment: Amazingly, 11.1 still does not do this, even though considerable hype is attached to showing an entirely useless and unreadable "preview" of the details section.

Answer (score 14):

### V11+ notes

Stylesheet solution does not seem to work and the section repeatedly opens and closes. I am not sure why yet.

If you are fine with details section permanently opened you can edit "Notebook" style and add:

```
NotebookDynamicExpression :> Refresh[
  CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], {TaggingRules, "Openers", "NotesSection"}] = True
  ,
  None
]
```

I was expecting it to work fine but somehow the section can't be closed (is reopened).

### Update 2015, stylesheet approach:

We can safely customize basic stylesheets by copying them first to `$UserBaseDirectory`:

```
styleDir = FileNameJoin[{"SystemFiles", "FrontEnd", "StyleSheets", "Wolfram"}]

If[! DirectoryQ@#, CreateDirectory@#] &@ FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, styleDir}]


CopyFile @@ (
  FileNameJoin[{#, styleDir, "Reference.nb"}] & /@ {
   $InstallationDirectory, $UserBaseDirectory}
 )

SetOptions[NotebookOpen @ %, {Editable -> True, Saveable -> True}]
```

Now find `"NotesSection"` style definitions and add there

```
CellDynamicExpression :> Refresh[
  SelectionMove[EvaluationCell[], All, CellGroup];
  FrontEndExecute[ FrontEndToken[EvaluationNotebook[], "OpenCloseGroup"]]
  ,
  None
]
```

[image]

Save and done.

---

### Old answer, programmatic approach

The idea is to capture <kbd>F1</kbd> (*take a look at the link at the bottom*) and include a code that will expand this cell group.

I have not fully tested it (*and I probably won't :P*) but this works so far:

#### V9:

```
    Unprotect[Documentation`HelpLookup];
    Documentation`HelpLookup[link_String, nb_, lang_String, opts : OptionsPattern[]
     ] := Block[{$inblock = True, test},

                test = Documentation`HelpLookup[link, nb, opts];
                NotebookFind[test, "NotesSection", All, CellStyle];
                FrontEndTokenExecute[test, "OpenCloseGroup"]

               ] /; ! TrueQ[$inblock]
```

90% of credits goes to [Simon Woods](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/862/simon-woods) for [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/41910/5478)

One can put it to the init.m file so this becomes a default behaviour. I've never done this but I will try one day.

I was trying to do this via `Cells[test, CellStyle->"NotesSection"]` but it was terminating the session repeatedly.

This works on Win7 V9 but not on V8. Any comments appreciated.

#### V8:

I can't test it and it is ugly but works on V8, thanks [Michael Hale](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/5568/michael-hale) for [help](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/15206459#15206459):

```
Unprotect[Documentation`HelpLookup];
Documentation`HelpLookup[link_String, nb_, lang_String, opts : OptionsPattern[]
   ] := Block[{$inblock = True, test},

   Documentation`HelpLookup[link, nb, opts];
   Pause[1];
   test =
    Select[Notebooks[], (("DocumentType" /. NotebookInformation[#]) ===
          "Help") &][[1]];
   NotebookFind[test, "NotesSection", All, CellStyle];
   FrontEndTokenExecute[test, "OpenCloseGroup"]] /; ! TrueQ[$inblock]
```

Unfortunatelly I can't make it work without `Pause` since I can;t test it. If I find V8 among my friends I will try to make a proper code.

Comment: Very nice. Another Necromancer badge coming up I think :-)

Comment: @SimonWoods Thanks to you for a lesson and SjoerdC.deVries for showing this question :)

Comment: Perhaps "copying" instead of "moving" is an even safer instruction?  [Seems like a trivial goal, opening the details section, but the use of `CellDynamicExpression` is certainly +1 material.]

Comment: @MichaelE2 Good point. Yes, strange design choice that there are no CellGroup options and inheritance mechanisms for those options. And thanks for +1 :)

Comment: 11.3 here. I am getting a pretty funny behavior. As soon as I open help, the Details section opens and closes by itself nonstop. It got me laughing by surprise, but did not solve the problem actually :)

Comment: @kkm with which solution?

Comment: Oh silly me. The second box from the top, `CellDynamicExpression :> ...` one. Clicking on the section stops the show, but any event, including a simple mouse move, resumes it.

Comment: @kkm daily fun with dynamic updating :( I was only able to fix it open and it will not close. If you are fine with that you need to use NotebookDynamicExpression :> Refresh[
  CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], {TaggingRules, "Openers", "NotesSection"}] = True
  ,
  None
]
 for Notebook style. Don't forget to delete NotesSection edits. I will try to investigate more later.

Comment: Thanks. I'm having that fun too. :(

Comment: Adding `AllowGroupClose->False` to the same style (in addition to that `CellDynamicExpression`) seems to have solved it. The section cannot be manually closed, naturally, but I can perfectly live with that. :)

Comment: @kkm I think this is the first time I see this option :) Will investigate later, thanks :)

Comment: When *you* say that, I am genuinely frightened! :)

Answer (score 3):

Based on [Kuba](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/5478/kuba)'s findings in [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/46894/280) and [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/141697/280) answers and also thanks to [user1950580](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/6395/user1950580) who uncovered `` FrontEnd`Private`SetCurrentValue `` (his [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/124645/280) was the only place where this function was listed), here is my modification of [Kuba](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/5478/kuba)'s *stylesheet approach* which works well with version 11.1 and is tuned on to influence other versions installed as little as possible. In order to prevent the appearance of the dialog

[image: screenshot]

in earlier versions (the above screenshot is from version 8 installed on the same machine) when opening the Documentation center (which automatically opens modified "Reference.nb" stylesheet), I `Export` new stylesheet as `"Package"`.

Here is the code:

```
systemStyleSubDir = FileNameJoin[{"SystemFiles", "FrontEnd", "StyleSheets", "Wolfram"}];

If[! DirectoryQ@#, CreateDirectory@#] &@
  FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, systemStyleSubDir}];

Export[FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, systemStyleSubDir, "Reference.nb"}],
 Notebook[{
   Cell[StyleData[
     StyleDefinitions -> 
      FrontEnd`FileName[{$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", "FrontEnd", "StyleSheets",
         "Wolfram", "Reference.nb"}]]],
   Cell[StyleData["NotesSection"],
    CellDynamicExpression :> FEPrivate`If[FEPrivate`Equal[FEPrivate`$VersionNumber, 11.1],
      FrontEnd`Private`SetCurrentValue[
             FrontEnd`ButtonNotebook[], {TaggingRules, "Openers", "NotesSection"}, 
       True]]]},
  StyleDefinitions -> "PrivateStylesheetFormatting.nb"], "Package"]
```

Note that `Refresh` isn't necessary here. I also use safe `` FrontEnd`ButtonNotebook[] `` instead of dangerous `SelectedNotebook[]` with which the above `CellDynamicExpression` will modify not exclusively the Documentation Notebook from where it is running, but any selected or currently evaluating Notebook if a `Cell` with the modified `"NotesSection"` style is currently displayed on the screen...

Comment: I don't understand when and why are you facing this dialog. I also don't understand how could `EvaluationNotebook[]` refer to any other notebook that the stylesheet child it is in. Could you add a context/example?

Comment: @Kuba This dialog appears when I open Documentation center of version 8 installed on the same machine because it opens the "Reference.nb" stylesheet exported from version 11.1. I haven't checked it with `EvaluationNotebook[]` but `SelectedNotebook[]` does modify any (for example, new) Notebook which is selected at the time when the Documentation cell with the modified `"NotesSection"` style is displayed on-screen.

Comment: Strange, in 10.4 it does not complain on 11.1 Reference.nb. I'm not using SelectedNotebooks and you claim EvaluationNotebook I use is dangerous :)