# How do I select a random sample without replacement?

Tags: probability-or-statistics

What is the module that selects a random sample of size k (without replacement) from a given population of size n, involving the command `Subsets`.

Comment: I have a problem with " without  replacement"

Comment: Enter "random sample", with or without quotes, in the Documentation Center. Check amongst the top hits and you should find something applicable.

Comment: I didn't find anything about without replacement

Comment: (1) What did you find? (2) What did the documentation state about what you found?

Comment: I found how to select a random sample... but there's nothing about "without replacement"

Comment: Click under Details. Always.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau So surely you can answer [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/35370/193)!

Comment: @Belisarius Not knowing how to do that, I defer to Shirley.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau http://www.whitepages.com/name/Shirley-Defer

Answer (score 6):

Well, they don't literally use the terminology "without replacement" in the manual, but One might expect you should know that is the same as saying "no elements occur more then once"..

Anyway..in summary there are two related functions:

```
RandomSample[list,k] -> "without replacement"
RandomChoice[list,k] -> "with replacement"
```

And to literally answer the question, if you insist on using Subsets,

```
RandomChoice@Subsets[list,{k}]
```

will also give a sample "without replacement". Note Subsets approach will be horribly slow for large lists since it generates all combinations then picks one.  (Subsets also orders the result which you may or may not want)

Just for fun you get respectable performance out of Subsets if you do this:

```
Subsets[list,{k},{RandomInteger[ Length[list]! / (Length[list]-k)! / k!]}]
```