# Way to expand all cells of a help doc page at once?

Tags: documentation

If I wish to look through a long documentation page (e.g., that for Integrate or Plot), I find it helpful to first expand all the cells. I can then search for what I seek with either a visual scan or a word search.  However, expanding all the cells manually is tedious—I have to individually click on each of the separate down-arrows, sub-down-arrows, and sub-sub-down-arrows (the page for Plot has a total of 50 of these!).

Is there a way to do this complete (i.e., recursive) expansion with a single command?  On a Mac, in a notebook, you can highlight all the cells with <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and then toggle back and forth between open and closed with <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>'</kbd>.  But this doesn't work in the help docs.

Comment: I don't know on Mac, but on Linux, after selecting all cells with Ctrl+A, pressing Ctrl+Shift+[ will open all cells.

Comment: @J.M. It's the equivalent on a Mac: cmd+A to highlight all cells, then either cmd+shift+[ or cmd + ' to open the highlighted cells (cmd + ' goes both ways, allowing you to toggle them open & closed; on Linux it's probably ctrl + ').  But (at least on a Mac) this doesn't work for the help menu, because you first have to expose the cells to highlight them, which requires first clicking all the down-arrows.  Are you saying that, in the help docs specifically, when using Linux,  just doing ctrl+A and ctrl+shift+[  will expose all the material?

Comment: I should probably note that I had modified the stylesheet for doc pages using [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/145608); I don't actually know if the "Details and Options" in the default stylesheet will expand in the manner I described.

Comment: Note that I don't just want to expand "Details and Options", I want to expand everything, including all the sub-topics under Examples, e.g., Scope, Options, Applications, etc., and all the sub-sub-topics under those (e.g., the various sub-sub-topics under Options).  With the mods you've made, does Ctrl+A then Ctrl+Shift+[ expand everything, or just Details and Options?

Comment: Yes, it all gets expanded on Linux. And, having tried now, it works on Windows too.

Comment: @theorist it'll work on all of them. Effectively what you've done is ``FrontEndExecute@{FrontEndToken["SelectAll"], 
  FrontEndToken["SelectionOpenAllGroups"]}``

Comment: Cmd+A followed by Cmd+Shift+[ works on OSX for me.

Comment: Thanks for all your help!  I figured out the problem.  I've long used cmd + ' to toggle back and forth between expanded and collapsed cells in notebooks (less typing than cmd + shift + [  and cmd + shift + ], plus I don't need to remember that you use a L bracket to open and a R bracket to close).  The problem is that cmd + ' doesn't work in the help docs; you have to use cmd + shift + [ .  Sorry to take up your time!  Should I put the correction in the original question, add it as an answer, or delete the question? [I'll do the first in the meantime.]

Comment: @theorist just self-answer. Better than having it in the question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While (on a Mac) <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>'</kbd> works to toggle cell groups open and closed in notebooks, it doesn't work in the help documentation.  There you have to instead use <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> (or, in Windows or Linux, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> ).

So to get it to work on all of the groups use <kbd>Cmd/Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> then <kbd>Cmd/Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd>

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It's superior to mine and more direct. If you mark it as such it'll percolate up higher and people won't see mine first.

Comment: Thanks; since it's a self-answer, the system won't allow me to accept it for two days.

Comment: @b3m2a1 Also, as it's a self-answer, it won't be sent to the top if accepted.

Answer (score 8):

Here's a way to do it programmatically in case that's ever useful:

```
FrontEndExecute@{FrontEndToken[InputNotebook[], "SelectAll"],
  FrontEndToken[InputNotebook[], "SelectionOpenAllGroups"]}
```

Or you can bind it to a button:

```
Button["Open Groups", 
 FrontEndExecute@{FrontEndToken[InputNotebook[], "SelectAll"], 
   FrontEndToken[InputNotebook[], "SelectionOpenAllGroups"]}
 ]
```

You could also bind it to the basic <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>'</kbd> event:

```
{
 {"MenuCommand", 
   "OpenCloseGroup"} :> {FrontEndToken[InputNotebook[], "SelectAll"], 
   FrontEndToken[InputNotebook[], "SelectionOpenAllGroups"]}
 }
```

Attach that to the `NotebookEventActions` at the stylesheet level for the `"Wolfram/Reference.nb"` stylesheet (making sure to make a copy in your `$UserBaseDirectory` to edit).